# "unbound identifier in module" error in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm writing a function in Racket, using DrRacket:

```
(define (same-parity a .b)
 (let ((remain (remainder a 2)))
  (define (recur-part remain-list)
   (cond ((= remain (remainder (car remain-list) 2))
         (append remain-list (list (car remain-list)))
         (recur-part (cdr remain-list)))
        (else (recur-part (cdr remain-list)))))
  (recur-part b)))
```

But the compiler complains the following:`b: unbound identifier in module in: b`

How could it be for the `(recur-part b)` is in the scope of the definition of `same-parity`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a space between `.` and `b`.

The problems is that `.b` is a legal name in Racket, so `.b` is in scope not `b`.

Comment: It works:) thx. Previously I thought `.` as a separator rather than a part of the name.

Comment: @Caesar Very easy mistake to make. In most languages it is a separator.